# x=5,6 if x==6 print 6 else print not 6

Tags: python-2.7

I have started learning python and using online interpreter for python 2.9-pythontutor

```
x=5,6
if x==5:
   print "5" 
else:
   print "not"
```

It goes in else loop and print not.
why is that?
what exactly x=5,6 means?

Comment: You could `print x` to see what's going on.

Comment: `x=5,6` is a tuple. You need to define `x=5` so it will go and print 5.

Comment: @Blind0ne it's a tuple, not a list.

Answer (score 2):

`,` is tuple expr, where `x,y` will return a tuple `(x,y)`

so expression `5,6` will return a tuple `(5,6)`

`x` is nether `5` nor `6` but a tuple

Comment: can I access elements of tuple ,like x[0]?

Answer (score 0):

When you declared `x = 5, 6` you made it a tuple. Then later when you do `x == 5` this translates to `(5, 6) == 5` which is not true, so the else branch is run.

If instead you did `x[0] == 5` that would be true, and print 5. Because we are accessing the 0 index of the tuple, which is equal to 5. Check out [some tutorials on tuples](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_tuples.htm) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

In Python when you write `x = 4, 5`, it is same as declaring a tuple as `x = (4, 5)`. In interpreter, if you write:

```
>>> x = 4, 5
>>> x
(4, 5)
```

Hence, it is similar to comparing a `tuple` with an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

X here acts as an array, where x is pointed to the first element of the array as x [0] = 5 and x [1] = 6

Execute this code, and the display will be 5

```
    x=5,6
     if x[0]==5:
       print "5" 
    else:
      print "not"
```

and try to See this link "http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit " you can run your code python step by step